# What is the equivalent keyword for extern in java?

Tags: java

I have one public static variable in one file and how can I export the same variable to other files?

For ex:-

file1.java

```
public final static int buf = 256;
```

file2.java

How can I access the variable "buf" in this file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`File1.buf`. More generally: `ClassName.FIELD_NAME`. A few notes

- use `CAPITAL_LETTERS` to name your static final fields (`BUF`)
- use `static final` rather than `final static` (not crucial, but it is a widely accepted style)

Comment: it is unimportant, but it is a widely accepted style. Checkstyle / PMD report it as a warning.

Comment: They do?  I would consider that unnecessary pickiness, but if it makes it more readable - fine with me.

Comment: it is not on in the default rulesets I think, but there's a rule for that

Comment: @Thor: Checkstyle / PMD *can* be pretty picky, but `static final` is **far** more common than `final static`.

Comment: I recently noticed that the order is also recommended in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1) - but as already noticed it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
File1.buf
```

correct definition: `public static final int BUF = 256;`

so you would call it in other class:

```
File1.BUF;
```